# Is there a reason Visual Studio 2010 is not generating Update and Delete statements on Typed DataSet using the designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

When using Visual Studio 2010 to update a typed dataset, it is updating the Insert command, but it simply deletes the Update and Delete commands.

I have the Generate Update commands set to true.

Any ideas why it isn't generating the other statements?

(This is a legacy app with lots of queries, so I can't just delete the Datatable and recreate it)

Answer (score 8):

It is because the table didn't have the primary key set in SQL Server.